# aws cli logs filter-pattern exclude

Tags: amazon-web-services, logging, design-patterns, filter, command-line-interface

I'm trying to get logs from an application running in AWS, while excluding logs that contain a certain phrase:

```
aws logs filter-log-events --log-group-name $MY_LOG_GROUP --filter-pattern -"dont want"
```

The above works. However, if I instead try:

```
aws logs filter-log-events --log-group-name $MY_LOG_GROUP --filter-pattern -"dontwant"
```

I get:

```
aws: error: argument --filter-pattern: expected one argument
```

I assume my shell is parsing it as an additional flag, instead of an argument to `--filter-pattern`. So, first question: How do I force aws cli to treat it as an argument?

If I instead try:

```
aws logs filter-log-events --log-group-name "$MY_LOG_GROUP" --filter-pattern -"GET /healthcheck"
```

I get:

```
An error occurred (InvalidParameterException) when calling the FilterLogEvents operation: Invalid filter pattern
```

Second question(s): what's the issue here, and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
aws logs filter-log-events --log-group-name $MY_LOG_GROUP --filter-pattern=-"dont want"
```

The `aws cli` supports the `<option>=<value>` syntax also. Looks like this has been an issue for [awhile](https://github.com/aws/aws-cli/issues/1135).

As for the second example, the slash causes issues but I think this works so it will not try to interpret the slash; also an issue for [awhile](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=217235):

```
aws logs filter-log-events --log-group-name "$MY_LOG_GROUP" --filter-pattern='-"GET /healthcheck"'
```

Comment: The second command works for me. Nothing else I've been trying will so this was a lifesaver! Thanks!